# Google Cloud Tasks "Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request."

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-tasks

I have a project with the following settings:

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 1
  max_instances: 6
  max_pending_latency: 15s

inbound_services:
- warmup
```

I have cronjobs that run each start of the hour, and each half of the hour. I have a queue called **events** which serves to run events from Slack. Those events need to be processed under 3s so i have put **--max-dispatches-per-second=500** and **--max-concurrent-dispatches=60** so they run as quickly as possible.

The two cronjobs tasks that run at 1 * * * * and 30 * * * * are used to send notifications to users(at time they specified). These cronjobs doesnt neccessary need to be that fast in processing so i have put **--max-dispatches-per-second=10** and **--max-concurrent-dispatches=2**.

My issue is that my events queue is getting a lot of "Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request." on start of each hour and at 30min. On other timeframe i dont get this, when these cronjobs are running my events queue is failing. My notifications queue(cronjob) used to have a lot higher dispatches and i reduced it to the numbers already mentioned but this is still happening.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction? What should be done here? Can i resolve this without increasing the number of max instances?

Comment: how long take your taks?

Comment: If you are refering to notification tasks, about 1-2s. I was thinking on adding a random schedule time delay to each task, maybe that will help.

Comment: I'm gonna state the obvious - it seems like there's a bottleneck in your app so it cant handle more requests at the same time. Do some profiling to see where the issue might be. You mentioned Slack. Maybe the Slack API is getting throttled when there's a spike in the amount of requests and that results in the behaviour you described.